# Error installing json 1.8.2 with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, windows

I'm new to web development and I have a school assignment this summer that requires Ruby on Rails. I'm using this guide currently to help me get started:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I'm using Windows 7 and most of the answers I have seen on this site are dealing with other operating systems or older versions of Ruby.

I installed Ruby which includes RubyGems and SQLite3 and here is a screen shot showing the versions and proves that they are installed:

[Version Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVaq1.jpg)

The issue I am running into is that when I try to create a Rails application I get an [error that says it occurred while installing json <1.8.2>. This is a new account so I can't post any screenshots or links. The last line says to make sure that 'gem install json -v '1.8.2' succeeds before bundling.

When I try that I get the same error as the previous step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to dev on Windows with RoR? It's a real pain... Last time I had to work on it I used Vagrant Debian VM, really better...

Comment: seems that it isn't compatibility with Ruby 2.2.0 https://github.com/flori/json/issues/229

Comment: @pangpang I seen a similar article saything there was conflicts with 2.2.0 so I guess that must be the issue. Julien Leray I think I will switch Operating Systems now since I haven't really started coding. Thanks to you both for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the RubyInstaller [Development Kit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/). This toolkit helps with using native C/C++ extensions for Ruby on your Windows machine.

Installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).

After it's installed, run `gem update --system`, then try again.

**A side note:** If you're not strict on your dev machine's OS, you should look into a Linux OS, or OSX. They provide a smoother experience for Rails development compared to Windows, IMO.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Be sure to add it to the PATH

Comment: @Zoran I don't have the reputation to give you a Vote Up but thanks for answering. I did install the Development Kit previously and I just tried the gem update --system command but the issue still occurred. I think I'll virtualize some Linux distribution and go from there. Thanks for the help.